# mosquitto_sub –d –t armtronix_mqtt Error: Unknown option '–d'

Tags: software-installation, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mqtt

What information can be gleaned for corrective action to enable subscription to the example MQTT topic?

The goal is to reproduce the test (subscribe & publish), per the  [instruction's Step 3](https://www.instructables.com/id/Installing-MQTT-BrokerMosquitto-on-Raspberry-Pi/): an MQTT server was installed and attempts to subscribe with MQTT Client fails:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mosquitto_sub –d –t armtronix_mqtt

**Error: Unknown option '–d'.**

Use 'mosquitto_sub --help' to see usage.
```

Help Page:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mosquitto_sub --help
mosquitto_sub is a simple mqtt client that will subscribe to a single topic and print all messages it receives.
mosquitto_sub version 1.4.10 running on libmosquitto 1.4.10.

Usage: mosquitto_sub [-c] [-h host] [-k keepalive] [-p port] [-q qos] [-R] -t topic ...
                     [-C msg_count] [-T filter_out]
                     [-A bind_address] [-S]
                     [-i id] [-I id_prefix]
                     [-d] [-N] [--quiet] [-v]
                     [-u username [-P password]]
                     [--will-topic [--will-payload payload] [--will-qos qos] [--will-retain]]
                     [{--cafile file | --capath dir} [--cert file] [--key file]
                      [--ciphers ciphers] [--insecure]]
                     [--psk hex-key --psk-identity identity [--ciphers ciphers]]
                     [--proxy socks-url]
       mosquitto_sub --help

 -A : bind the outgoing socket to this host/ip address. Use to control which interface
      the client communicates over.
 -c : disable 'clean session' (store subscription and pending messages when client disconnects).
 -C : disconnect and exit after receiving the 'msg_count' messages.
 -d : enable debug messages.
 -h : mqtt host to connect to. Defaults to localhost.
 -i : id to use for this client. Defaults to mosquitto_sub_ appended with the process id.
 -I : define the client id as id_prefix appended with the process id. Useful for when the
      broker is using the clientid_prefixes option.
 -k : keep alive in seconds for this client. Defaults to 60.
 -N : do not add an end of line character when printing the payload.
 -p : network port to connect to. Defaults to 1883.
 -P : provide a password (requires MQTT 3.1 broker)
 -q : quality of service level to use for the subscription. Defaults to 0.
 -R : do not print stale messages (those with retain set).
 -S : use SRV lookups to determine which host to connect to.
 -t : mqtt topic to subscribe to. May be repeated multiple times.
 -T : topic string to filter out of results. May be repeated.
 -u : provide a username (requires MQTT 3.1 broker)
 -v : print published messages verbosely.
 -V : specify the version of the MQTT protocol to use when connecting.
      Can be mqttv31 or mqttv311. Defaults to mqttv31.
 --help : display this message.
 --quiet : don't print error messages.
 --will-payload : payload for the client Will, which is sent by the broker in case of
                  unexpected disconnection. If not given and will-topic is set, a zero
                  length message will be sent.
 --will-qos : QoS level for the client Will.
 --will-retain : if given, make the client Will retained.
 --will-topic : the topic on which to publish the client Will.
 --cafile : path to a file containing trusted CA certificates to enable encrypted
            certificate based communication.
 --capath : path to a directory containing trusted CA certificates to enable encrypted
            communication.
 --cert : client certificate for authentication, if required by server.
 --key : client private key for authentication, if required by server.
 --ciphers : openssl compatible list of TLS ciphers to support.
 --tls-version : TLS protocol version, can be one of tlsv1.2 tlsv1.1 or tlsv1.
                 Defaults to tlsv1.2 if available.
 --insecure : do not check that the server certificate hostname matches the remote
              hostname. Using this option means that you cannot be sure that the
              remote host is the server you wish to connect to and so is insecure.
              Do not use this option in a production environment.
 --psk : pre-shared-key in hexadecimal (no leading 0x) to enable TLS-PSK mode.
 --psk-identity : client identity string for TLS-PSK mode.
 --proxy : SOCKS5 proxy URL of the form:
           socks5h://[username[:password]@]hostname[:port]
           Only "none" and "username" authentication is supported.
```

MQTT Client install log:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  coinor-libipopt1v5 libmumps-seq-4.10.0 libraw15
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmosquitto1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmosquitto1 mosquitto-clients
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 99.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 222 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf libmosquitto1 armhf 1.4.10-3+deb9u4 [47.2 kB]
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf mosquitto-clients armhf 1.4.10-3+deb9u4 [52.3 kB]
Fetched 99.5 kB in 1s (86.7 kB/s)           
Selecting previously unselected package libmosquitto1:armhf.
(Reading database ... 141867 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libmosquitto1_1.4.10-3+deb9u4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking libmosquitto1:armhf (1.4.10-3+deb9u4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mosquitto-clients.
Preparing to unpack .../mosquitto-clients_1.4.10-3+deb9u4_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking mosquitto-clients (1.4.10-3+deb9u4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up libmosquitto1:armhf (1.4.10-3+deb9u4) ...
Setting up mosquitto-clients (1.4.10-3+deb9u4) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
```

`.list` file install for Raspbian buster:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d $ sudo wget http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-buster.list
--2019-08-01 00:01:16--  http://repo.mosquitto.org/debian/mosquitto-buster.list
Resolving repo.mosquitto.org (repo.mosquitto.org)... 85.119.83.194, 2001:ba8:1f1:f271::2
Connecting to repo.mosquitto.org (repo.mosquitto.org)|85.119.83.194|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 50 [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘mosquitto-buster.list’

mosquitto-buster.list               100%[===================================================================>]      50  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2019-08-01 00:01:17 (1.14 MB/s) - ‘mosquitto-buster.list’ saved [50/50]

pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d $ mosquitto_sub –t armtronix_mqtt
Error: Unknown option '–t'.

Use 'mosquitto_sub --help' to see usage.
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d $ sudo apt-get install mosquitto-clients
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mosquitto-clients is already the newest version (1.4.10-3+deb9u4).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  coinor-libipopt1v5 libmumps-seq-4.10.0 libraw15
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d $ mosquitto_sub –t armtronix_mqtt
Error: Unknown option '–t'.

Use 'mosquitto_sub --help' to see usage.
pi@raspberrypi:/etc/apt/sources.list.d $ mosquitto_sub -d –t  armtronix_mqtt
Error: Unknown option '–t'.

Use 'mosquitto_sub --help' to see usage.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what character you're typing for `-` but it's the wrong one. You should be using a simple minus/hyphen/dash character but you seem to be using a longer dash of some sort:

```
–t    incorrect
-t    correct
```

On my UK keyboard it's the key between <kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>=</kbd>, used without shift.

Comment: Brilliant!  How did you manage to catch this subtle error?   I copied and paste the commands from the instructions and could not find the problematic character on the keyboard

Comment: There was nothing obviously wrong with `-d` but the app objected. Looking closer I was able to see the difference on the two `code`-formatted lines in your first block.

Comment: You might like to send feedback to the original article author to let them know their examples can't be copied and pasted so that others don't have the same problem in the future.

Comment: @oamima Agreed.  After successfully testing, I used the web's feedback mechanisms to communicate the issue.